# How to publish specific branch to azure app service?

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

I have code in VSTS. I have azure app service.

I can manually deploy from Visual Studio to azure via Publish Config Profile.

I setup continue integration deploy, now I somebody push to master branch it will be deployed on azure.

How to publish specific branch to azure app service? Main goal what QA can deploy any branch without VS.

I can't find any whay, except make a lot of CMD command like, login to VSTS, get files, upload to server, run server.

Comment: Another issue of yours has been solved, this issue is similar, do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy to azure app service by using [Azure App Service Deployment step/task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment). For example:

1. Create a build definition
2. Add related step/task to build your project
3. Add Azure App Service Deployment step/task (Can publish using Web Deploy or upload files directly)
4. Select Triggers tab and enable Continuous Integration
5. Specify repository and branch filters

After that, the build will be triggered if you push changes to target branch.

Related article: [Define a continuous integration build for your Node.js app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/node/nodejs-to-azure), [Continuous deployment to Azure for ASP.NET Core, with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/vsts-continuous-deployment)

On the other hand, you also could deploy app through Azure continuous delivery (CD), more information, you can refer to: [Use Azure to automatically generate a CI/CD pipeline to deploy an ASP.NET app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/aspnet-4-ci-cd-azure-automatic)

Answer (score 1):

and if you got here trying to google how to get it working for local git deployment option, here is the answer: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-branch

> you can set the branch by setting an Azure App Setting called
>   `deployment_branch`.